# How To: Custom HTML snippets for different object types in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a little problem trying to convert a piece of software from Knockout.js to Angular.js

Lets say I have the following data returned from a database:

```
{
    id: "Some ID",
    title: "Some Template",
    fields: [
        {type: "radio", title="Some Title", description: "Some Description},
        {type: "textbox", title="Some Title", description: "Some Description},
        {type: "radio", title="Some Title", description: "Some Description}
    ]
}
```

In Knockout.js I could simple create if statements that allow me to drop in the appropriate html like so:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.myData.fields -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.type === "textbox" !-->
        <input type="textbox" id="whatever" />
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

I'm at a loss at how to replicate the above behavior in Angular. Would I use a custom directive? If so how would it be structured?

Currently I'm trying something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in review.fields">
    <div class="review-temp-left">
        <div class="title">{{ field.title }}</div>
        <div class="desc">{{ field.description }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-temp-right">
    <!-- NEED TO MAKE THIS AREA LOAD APPROPRIATE HTML FOR INPUT TYPE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Aric

Comment: Use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) to load appropriate HTML based on `type`.

Comment: You sir, are my hero for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) can be used to add the appropriate HTML content to the DOM, based on the `type`.

Note that ng-show/ng-hide currently do not add/remove content from the DOM like ng-switch does – they only manipulate CSS properties to hide/show DOM content.